# Select TD elements, except the ones in these parent TR

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I want it to ignore the `<td>` that has a parent of class `.ignore`. Here is what I have now, but it styles every `<td>`.

```
<script>
$('td:nth-child(2)').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 248, 231)');
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>select</td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ignore">
        <td> </td>
        <td>don't select</td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>select</td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('tr:not(.ignore) td').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 248, 231)');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dbZxw/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').not('tr.ignore td').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 248, 231)');​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3TrxJ/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
    if ($(this).closest('tr').hasClass('ignore') === false){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 248, 231)');
    }
});
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2vx3u/1/)